# Can someone explain the algorithm?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I need function with parameters as (LinkedList one,LinkedList two)

so, how to set/define the head and current for both the list seperately??

I dont know why this question was closed.
But I am new to java and need to solve this so can anybody help???

to check if a list is subset of another, I have this code from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/)

HERE IT IS CODE IF WE PASS NODE IN THE PARAMETER LIKE (Node one,Node two) but I want parameters as (linkedlist one,liked list two) so can anyone explain algorithm to do so???

```
static boolean checkSubSet(Node first, Node second) { 
    Node ptr1 = first, ptr2 = second; 
  
    // If both linked lists are empty, 
    // return true 
    if (first == null && second == null) 
        return true; 
  
    // Else If one is empty and  
    // other is not, return false 
    if (first == null || 
       (first != null && second == null)) 
        return false; 
  
    // Traverse the second list by  
    // picking nodes one by one 
    while (second != null) 
    { 
        // Initialize ptr2 with  
        // current node of second 
        ptr2 = second; 
  
        // Start matching first list  
        // with second list 
        while (ptr1 != null) 
        { 
            // If second list becomes empty and  
            // first not then return false 
            if (ptr2 == null) 
                return false; 
  
            // If data part is same, go to next 
            // of both lists 
            else if (ptr1.data == ptr2.data) 
            { 
                ptr1 = ptr1.next; 
                ptr2 = ptr2.next; 
            } 
  
            // If not equal then break the loop 
            else break; 
        } 
  
        // Return true if first list gets traversed 
        // completely that means it is matched. 
        if (ptr1 == null) 
            return true; 
  
        // Initialize ptr1 with first again 
        ptr1 = first; 
  
        // And go to next node of second list 
        second = second.next; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

but how to do the same thing by passing the actual linked lists as a parameter for eg

```
static boolean checkSubSet(Node first, Node second){}
```

instead of this I want to do this

```
static boolean checkSubSet(LinkedList<Integer> list1,LinkedList<Integer> list2){}
```

Comment: its not my code. Thats why I said "i have this code" and not "I wrote this code". Anyway thanks for pointing it out, I edited the question and gave the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refactor your code so it accepts `java.util.LinkedList` as an argument. Well, I see that your code is from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sublist-search-search-a-linked-list-in-another-list/). The [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sublist-search-search-a-linked-list-in-another-list/) assumes that you have your own linked list implementation. It also assumes you have access to the `next` and `data` parts of the linked list nodes. Unfortunately, java `LinkedList` does not expose those, so your code is not useful for your question.

You need to design a new algorithm for the Java `LinkedList`. Since `LinkedList` is not a `Set`. It is not very meaningful to execute set functions over a `LinkedList`. However,
if you really need, you may use something like that:

```
return new HashSet(a).containsAll(new HashSet(b));
```

or, iterate over the lists to get what you want.